# Fill out content area of orbit slider

Tags: zurb-foundation

How do I go about configuring orbit so that the images fill out the whole viewing area?

At the moment i have a gallery with two images. These images are not as wide as the viewing area of the orbit slider and it looks kind of dull presenting them like this. 
Is there a way to configure orbit so the whole viewing area is filled?

Look at this picture. In the top is how the orbit image is being rendered and in the botton is how i would like it to be rendered instead. Is there any way to do this or do i need to crop and resize all images myself?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code you are using? Also, what size are the images that you are using? When I've done this, I typically have cropped the images larger than the area I want them to cover. On one site that I'm working on, I have them cropped at 1600x500.

Here is what that site is using right now:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-12 large-centered columns">
        <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
            <span class="preloader"></span>
                <ul id="featured1" data-orbit data-options="pause_on_hover:false; timer_speed:5500;">
                    <li><img src="/assets/sliders/slider01.jpg" /> <div class="orbit-caption">...</div></li>
                    <li><img src="/assets/sliders/slider02.jpg" /> <div class="orbit-caption">...</div></li>
                    <li><img src="/assets/sliders/slider03.jpg" /> <div class="orbit-caption">...</div></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The additional class="slideshow-wrapper" is in there so I can further customize the text, etc.

Comment: My code looks like this:
<ul class="example-orbit" data-orbit>
    @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
    {
        var media = Model[index];
        <li>
            <img src="@(Model[index].VirtualPath)" alt="" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

I can make it work if i resize and scale the images but that shouldn't be needed i think. Lots of other sliders makes the images adapt to the content area

Comment: So you could try something like this:  .example-orbit img { width: 100%; height: auto; }  That will tell it that you want the images inside that container to be as big as the container.  The downside is that if you have something really tall, it will stretch the container down the page to fill it.  So you could add "overflow: hidden", then set a max-height: 375px;.  Then it will essentially "crop" the image to fit the width and a height of 375px.  Not sure what browser support is off the top of my head, so be sure to test!

Comment: Sadly since the orbit script sets the height automaticly based on the biggest image height, that means i cant set a fixed height and setting overflow hidde. I think i'll try finding another to accomplish what I need. Thanks for all the help though!